# postgreSQL sorting with timestamps

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM schema."table"
  WHERE "TimeStamp"::timestamp >= '2016-03-09 03:00:05'
  ORDER BY "TimeStamp"::date asc
  LIMIT 15
```

What do I expect it to do? Giving out 15 rows of the table, where the timestamp is the same and bigger than that date, in ascending order. But postgres sends the rows in the wrong order. The first item is on the last position. [image: SQL Editor with result]
So has anyone an idea why the result is this strange?

Comment: if you could write it as an answer I could mark it as the correct one and give you a +1 for it.

Comment: Because you casted the field `Timestamp`into `date` data_type, which does not care about `time`(hh:mm:ss) info. Try order without casting

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use simply `ORDER BY "TimeStamp"` (without casting to date).

Answer (score 4):

By casting `"TimeStamp"` to `date` you throw away the time part of the timestamp, so all values within one day will be considered equal and are returned in random order. It is by accident that the first rows appear in the order you desire.

Don't cast to `date` in the `ORDER BY` clause if the time part is relevant for sorting.

Perhaps you are confused because Oracle's `DATE` type has a time part, which PostgreSQL's doesn't.