# Doing a group by on the given data set for stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a table with sample data as below:

```
  systemuid       filename           mindatetime                 maxdatetime
    10006       monitor_7.dat   2019-06-05 03:06:18.001 AM  2019-06-06 03:06:11.0 AM
    72111       monitor_4.dat   2019-04-28 09:00:00 AM      2019-04-29 11:00:00 AM
    10006       monitor_5.dat   2019-04-28 07:00:00 AM      2019-04-28 10:00:00 AM
    90204       monitor_7.dat   2019-05-24 03:06:11.001 AM  2019-06-05 03:06:18.0 AM
    90204       monitor_4.dat   2019-04-28 09:30:00 AM      2019-04-29 23:00:00 PM
    72111       monitor_7.dat   2019-04-21 03:06:26.0 AM    2019-05-21 03:06:10.0 AM
    10006       monitor_5.dat   2019-04-28 02:00:00 PM      2019-04-28 06:00:00 PM
    72111       monitor_7.dat   2019-05-12 07:00:10.001 AM  2019-05-13 10:00:10.000 AM
    90204       monitor_5.dat   2019-04-28 09:00:00 AM      2019-04-28 03:00:00 PM
    10006       monitor_7.dat   2019-05-15 09:30:10.001 AM  2019-05-18 11:30:10.000 AM
    72111       monitor_4.dat   2019-04-28 07:00:00 AM      2019-04-29 11:00:00 AM
    10006       monitor_7.dat   2019-05-21 03:06:10.001 AM  2019-05-24 03:06:11.0 AM
```

I want to organize the data by grouping the systemuid and filename and then order by mindatetime, maxdatetime. Each systemuid will have multiple filenames with each filename having multiple timestamps.

```
  systemuid       filename           mindatetime                 maxdatetime
    10006       monitor_5.dat   2019-04-28 07:00:00 AM      2019-04-28 10:00:00 AM
    10006       monitor_5.dat   2019-04-28 02:00:00 PM      2019-04-28 06:00:00 PM
    10006       monitor_7.dat   2019-05-15 09:30:10.001 AM  2019-05-18 11:30:10.000 AM
    10006       monitor_7.dat   2019-05-21 03:06:10.001 AM  2019-05-24 03:06:11.0 AM
    10006       monitor_7.dat   2019-06-05 03:06:18.001 AM  2019-06-06 03:06:11.0 AM
    72111       monitor_4.dat   2019-04-28 07:00:00 AM      2019-04-29 11:00:00 AM
    72111       monitor_4.dat   2019-04-28 09:00:00 AM      2019-04-29 11:00:00 AM
    72111       monitor_7.dat   2019-04-21 03:06:26.0 AM    2019-05-21 03:06:10.0 AM
    72111       monitor_7.dat   2019-05-12 07:00:10.001 AM  2019-05-13 10:00:10.000 AM
    90204       monitor_4.dat   2019-04-28 09:30:00 AM      2019-04-29 23:00:00 PM
    90204       monitor_5.dat   2019-04-28 09:00:00 AM      2019-04-28 03:00:00 PM
    90204       monitor_7.dat   2019-05-24 03:06:11.001 AM  2019-06-05 03:06:18.0 AM
```

I need this as a cursor for my stored procedure. So need the data to be in this format to perform the functionality on the records. The table size is pretty huge with millions of records.

Comment: What have you tried before? and what was the result? It seems to be a simple `order by` problem but needs more information

Comment: Columns `mindatetime` and `maxdatetime` are i assume stored in CHAR / VARCHAR format?

Comment: @RaymondNijland No, these columns are timestamps.

Comment: @Muhammadvakili Just a order by will sort the entire data set, what I need is to sort the min and max datetime for each systemuid and filename.

Comment: Shouldn't  this just work for you `ORDER BY systemuid, filename, mindatetime, maxdatetime` as you mentioned `mindatetime` and `maxdatetime` are `timestamps`

Comment: *"No, these columns are timestamps."* Not from the looks in the example data because off the added AM/PM..

Comment: still, even if they are timestamps they should be sorted.look
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457297/postgresql-sorting-with-timestamps

Comment: @MJoy Yes, the sort by approach works for small data sets. The table I am concerned with is huge having more than 20 million records without any primary key or index. So its taking a lot of time for execution. Any other way around?

Comment: @RaymondNijland: the AM/PM _display_ doesn't rule out timestamps if that is the default output format for the SQL client used.

Comment: true @a_horse_with_no_name but that is not what i meant here? As in the example data those columns now looks like CHAR / VARCHAR datatypes instead off one of the native date datatypes..

Comment: @Abhilash28Abhi I can't think about any optimal workaround for that, you should seriously think about creating index especially when you have 20 million data

Comment: @RaymondNijland: you claimed that those columns ca not be timestamps because of the AM/PM display. But they can still be timestamp columns if the client is configured to display them like that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name never mind we talk past one and other right now.. Not going into the discussion of SQL IDE display configuration ...

Answer (score 0):

Just use window functions:

```
order by systemuid, filename, mindatetime, maxdatetime
```

If you are concerned about performance on large datasets, be sure you have an index on `(systemuid, filename, mindatetime, maxdatetime)`.

Regardless of whether or not you have the index, it is probably faster to do the ordering in the database rather than in the application.